# collect score from mouse click event in c# silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, visual-studio-2012, mouseevent

Ok I am new to silverlight in c# and I am building a game where balloons float around the screen and you get points for clicking one.

I so far have 5 balloons moving randomly around and I wish to have a mouse click even for all of them.

so far for a mouse click I have

C#

```
private void redballoon_click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        // +1 to score array 
    }
```

XAML

```
<Image Height="53" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="red" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="48" Source="red.png" MouseLeftButtonDown="redballoon_click" Canvas.Left="194" Canvas.Top="161" RenderTransformOrigin="0.938,0.536" />
```

I would like some way of collecting the score for each click but I am very new and could do with some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a field in your class to track how many clicks, it will look something like this:

```
public class Window
{
    private int _clicks = 0;

    private void redballoon_click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        _clicks++; 
    }
}
```